# Does this level 10 multiclass combo work?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, optimization, multi-classing

I crafted a level 10 multiclass ranged oneshot character that has a lot of interactions and I was wondering if I did this right.

The race is not specified but should be something with +1 to dex for a total of 16 dex.

- A longbow: 1d8 + 3 (Dex)
- 3 levels in ranger with the Gloom Stalker archetype, for the Dread
  Ambusher trait and the Archery fighting style:

Dread Ambusher hit = 1d8 + 3 (longbow) + 1d8 + 3 (Dread Ambusher hit) + 1d8 (Dread Ambusher extra damage).

This has a +9 to hit: 3 (Dex) + 4 (prof. bonus) + 2 (Archery)

- 2 levels in fighter, for the Action Surge feature and the Close
  Quarters Shooter fighting style (from [Unearthed Arcana: Light, Dark,
  Underdark!](https://media.wizards.com/2015/downloads/dnd/02_UA_Underdark_Characters.pdf)).

That means 2 Dread Ambusher hits and an extra +1 to hit.

- 4 levels in rogue (with the Assassin archetype), for the Sneak Attack and
  Assassinate features, and an ASI.
  ASI increases Dex score to 18, for a +4 mod.

The Dread Ambusher hit then becomes: 1d8 + 4 (longbow) + 1d8 + 4 (Dread Ambusher hit) + 1d8 (Dread Ambusher extra damage).

Then add the Sneak Attack damage (2d6) and possible crit on surprise.

- 1 level in cleric with the Zeal Domain (from [Plane Shift:
  Amonkhet](https://media.wizards.com/2017/downloads/magic/plane-shift_amonkhet.pdf)), for the Priest of Zeal trait, which gives an extra
  weapon attack as a bonus action when the Attack action is used.

Then the total comes to:

(1d8 + 4 + 1d8 + 4 + 1d8) * 2 + 2d8 + 1d8 + 4  with possible crit if they are surprised.

This takes 3 attack rolls with a +11 to hit, with possible advantage if I'm first: 4 (Dex) + 4 (prof. bonus) + 3 (from 2 fighting styles).

**Do all of these interactions work, or am I overlooking something?**

Comment: You don't add proficiency to your damage. And I'm not sure what the question is? Are you asking if each of the features work with each other? Also, where is this zeal domain cleric?

Comment: @L0neGamer i will edit to clerify

Comment: @darnok There's still the issue of proficiency not being a part of the damage. Are you adding it on purpose, and if so, why? Do you have something in mind that lets you add proficiency to your damage?

Comment: @kviiri it apears that i have done damage rolls wrong for about a year now. ill remove the proficiency.

Comment: Ranger 5 + Fighter 2 + Assassin 3 = 10, and you have Extra Attack

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Your build works

I will start by saying that there is nothing specifically stopping this multi-class combination. You need 13 DEX for the Rogue/Fighter/Ranger combo, and 13 WIS for Cleric, but that isn't too tricky.

So:

> First shot: 1d8 + 3
>
> Dread Ambusher: 1d8 + 3 + 1d8
>
> Sneak Attack: 2d6
>
> Second attack: 1d8 + 3
>
> **Total: 4d8 + 2d6 + 12**

Add in Action Surge:

> First shot: 1d8 + 3
>
> Dread Ambusher: 1d8 + 3 + 1d8
>
> **Total: 3d8 + 6**

As you know you don't get Sneak Attack more than once a turn, but at the cost of your reaction you could ready your second action (from Action Surge) to attack with the trigger "as soon as anyone moves", and you will qualify for Sneak Attack on someone else's turn. You don't have a much better use of your reaction.

Also the second attack from the Zeal domain is a limited resource use of the bonus action. So not only will you only get a few uses a day, but it is removing your ability to hide, so you may lose out on Sneak Attack opportunities.

Note: What you are looking at only works on the first round of a combat, and only once per short rest, so more generally your damage is just 2d8 + 2d6 + 6. You can probably do better damage with less multi-classing.

Comment: "at the cost of your reactions you could hold your second attack for 'as soon as anyone moves' and you qualify for sneak attack on someone else's turn" - Can you source this? It seems Sneak Attack's "Once per turn" means once per your character's turn and using your reaction to perform a readied action is still part of the character's turn, isn't it?

Comment: @Longspeak: No. Readied actions happen whenever their trigger occurs (after the trigger). If you ready an attack for when the enemy gets within 5 feet of you, then if they move next to you on their turn, you're attacking on their turn - not yours.

Comment: I understood that to be your intent. But can you provide the source of that? When I read the PHB, I take a very different meaning from the text.

Comment: NM. It's not clear in the PHB, but I did find a source to support that at WotC.

Comment: The phrasing they use for what you *think* it says is "Once on each of your turns" versus "Once per turn".